# Find a value of $a$ for which line segment equals 4

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $f(x)=2^{x+1}+2^{4-x}$
>
> There is a value of $a$ for which the line $y=a$ intersects the graph of $f$ in two points $P$ and $Q$. The length of the line segment $PQ$ equals $4$.

I tried to figure it out on my own. Looking at the graph I saw that $y=a$ would intercept the graph twice from $f$'s minima, which is at $x=3/2$. Yet I'm unsure how to make an equation that would give me the answer regarding the line segment.

Would appreciate help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if for some $b$ we have $f(b)=a$ then we have $f(b+4)=a$ (or $f(b-4)=a)$) .

So $$2^{b+1}+2^{4-b} = 2^{b+5}+2^{-b}$$

so $$2^{-b}(2^4-1)=  2^{b+1}(2^4-1)\implies 2^{b+1}= 2^{-b}\implies b=-{1\over 2}$$

so $a = f(-1/2) = 17\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Thank you, you made a small mistake there on the final answer. It's $17\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(3/2+x)=2^{3/2+x+1}+2^{4-(3/2+x)}=2^{\frac52+x}+2^{\frac52-x}$$

$$f(3/2-x)=2^{3/2-x+1}+2^{4-(3/2-x)}=2^{\frac52+x}+2^{\frac52-x}$$

That is we have $$f(3/2+x)=f(3/2-x)$$

The graph is symmetrical about $x=\frac32$.

Hence the $x$ values for the two points are $\frac32+2$ and $\frac32-2$.

Having that we should be able to find the value of $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong.

Let $z:=2^x$, then

$2z+2^4z^{-1}= a$, or

$z^2 -(a/2)z +2^3=0.$

Note:

$z_1/z_2= 2^{x_1-x_2}= 2^4$.

$z_1×z_2 = 2^3$ (Vieta).

$z_1^2 = 2^7$; or

$z_1=2^{3+1/2}$; i.e

$x_1=3+1/2$, and  $x_2=-1/2$.

$-a/2= -z_1-z_2$ (Vieta);

$a=2(2^{3+1/2}+2^{-1/2})=$

$2^{4}2^{1/2} + 2^{1/2}=√2(17)$.